# Tag: Avatar: The last Airbender

Tags: discussion, status-completed

In [this question](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/2562/what-can-energybending-do/), I mentioned that the tag [avatar-the-last-airbender](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/avatar-the-last-airbender) may not the best choice for the question, as the tag only covers the first series, *Avatar: The last Airbender*. The question, however covers both, *Avatar: The last Airbender* and *The Legend of Korra*. Should there be a second tag [the-legend-of-korra](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-legend-of-korra), or should the Avatar-Tag be generalized? A new tag can make searches more specific, however both series are simply referred to as *Avatar*, most times.

Comment: Seeing as how it's not even anime, it should, IMO, not even be allowed on this site.

Comment: @coleopterist: That was already [discussed](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6697/conversation/third-chat-cast-expanding-our-scope-2013-02-09) and it was decided to allow it as a pilot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that in this case, the [avatar](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/avatar) tag should be created and used for both The Last Airbender and The Legend of Korra.  Madara's example of having a [naruto](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/naruto) and [naruto-shippuuden](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/naruto-shippuuden) tag to tell the two series apart isn't a very good one since everybody just uses the plain Naruto tag for both series.

To deal with differentiating the two series, I propose that [avatar](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/avatar) be used for both with related synonyms for [avatar-the-last-airbender](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/avatar-the-last-airbender) and [legend-of-korra](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legend-of-korra).  This way searching "avatar" will yield results for both series as they're both commonly referred to as Avatar and searching for either of the synonyms will give results for those particular series.

Comment: Are you sure that [tag:avatar] will not be used for anything else? Other than The last Airbender or Legend of Korra? Is there no other anime which includes "avatar" in the name?

Comment: I'm not exactly a fountain of knowledge when it comes to names of anime/manga but I don't know of any off the top of my head.  I'm sure it could be used for other animes though if they use the word avatar in the name.

Comment: Using a single tag to reference a series and a contiuation of that series is fine. Using a single tag for a lot of different series is not.

Answer (score 0):

I think a second tag is in order. If we have [naruto](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/naruto) and [naruto-shippuuden](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/naruto-shippuuden), we should have both tags.

Questions from both tags can be searched for by searching for [avatar*].

Comment: I should learn how to use the search ...

Comment: I'm not entirely certain your example was a very good one considering nobody uses the shippuuden tag.  All Naruto questions have been asked under the generalized Naruto tag whether they're from the original series or shippuuden.  In fact, looking at that tells me that it might be better to just have a generic avatar tag and use the other two tags as synonyms.

Comment: @MCeley: Hmmm, didn't think of that (*Y U NO DOWNVOTE?!*). That may be true. Post an answer detailing it, and see how many votes you get.

Comment: I use the main sites a lot but rarely use meta. My bad yo!